Purposefully modelling longitudinal data as iid?
I am thinking about working on a project in which there are individuals with repeated measures (i.e. multiple individuals and each individuals had multiple measurements). The response is binary (0,1) and I am thinking of using a logistic regression. I am thinking of different modelling strategies that account for correlation, but I am also worried about violating statistical assumptions by incorrectly including the response within the model.

1) Non-Standard approach: Treat each measurement for each individual as iid with a ratio of previous responses variable and an offset variable.
This is my own idea.
Here is the basic model:
$$ P(y_i = 1) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1)}} $$
Now, make the following modification to account for correlations:

Let $x_2$ represent the total number of measurements for person $i$
Let $x_3$ represent the ratio of ones to zeros in the previous measurements for person $i$
A time effect $t$ could possibly added

These are like cumulative running variables at the individual level. E.g. For individual i, response_4 ~ f(information of individual i from time points 1,2,3).
$x_2$ is used to account for individuals with more observations compared to less observations (e.g. an individual that has three measurements and all three are 1's compared to the same individual down the road that has 10 measurements and all are still 1):
$$ P(y_i = 1) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_3)}} $$
$$ \text{logit}[P(y_i = 1)] = \ln\left(\frac{P(y_i = 1)}{1 - P(y_i = 1)}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_3 $$
To handle the problem of 0 division, this model requires each individual to have at least 2 observations.
2) Standard strategy: Use a longitudinal model.
A standard logistic regression with repeated measures, for individual $i$ and the time point $t$:
$$ P(y_{it} = 1) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_{it})}} $$
$$ \text{logit}[P(y_{it} = 1)] = \ln\left(\frac{P(y_{it} = 1)}{1 - P(y_{it} = 1)}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{it} $$
Now to account for correlation between measurements from the same individual by using random effect term for each individual $u_i$:
$$ \text{logit}(P(y_{it} = 1)) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{it} + u_i $$
$$ u_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2_u) $$
An additional time effect can be added:
$$ \text{logit}(P(y_{it} = 1)) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{it} + \beta_2t + u_i $$
3) Autoregressive error structure
For an AR(1) error structure, define the error term $\epsilon_{it}$ as:
$$ \epsilon_{it} = \rho\epsilon_{i,t-1} + \eta_{it} $$
where:

$\rho$ is the autocorrelation parameter (with $|\rho| < 1$)
$\epsilon_{i,t-1}$ is the error term from the previous time point
$\eta_{it}$ is a new random error term: $\eta_{it} \sim N(0, \sigma^2_\eta)$

Putting everything together:
$$ \text{logit}(P(y_{it} = 1)) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{it} + \rho\epsilon_{i,t-1} + \eta_{it} $$
$$ \text{Cov}(\epsilon_{is}, \epsilon_{it}) = \sigma^2_\epsilon\rho^{|t-s|} $$

I am interested in hearing opinions about the first modelling approach? I think it would be computationally simpler to use approach 1 since it treats everything as iid. It also might be easier to explain the model and does not require the same types of assumptions on correlation structure. But in general, has anyone ever encountered approach 1? Is it statistically valid or is it breaking some statistical assumptions (e.g. endogeneity, multicollinearity)?

Note: I realize that in approach 1), there might be some information loss in the ratio calculation. For example, (0,0,0,1) would be treated the same way as (1,0,0,0). To account for this, I thought maybe a temporally weighted ratio could be useful?
$$ x_{3,it} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{t-1} w_j y_{i,t-j}}{\sum_{j=1}^{t-1} w_j} $$
$$ w_j = \alpha^{j-1} $$
where:

$y_{i,t-j}$ is the response (0 or 1) for individual $i$ at time point $t_j$
$w_j$ are the weights
$\alpha$ is a decay parameter (that we choose beforehand) between 0 and 1 (larger $\alpha$ gives more weight to older observations whereas smaller  $\alpha$ gives more weight to newer observations)
The weights are between 0 and 1


Just have lme model with within subject intercepts and slopes based on t, what is the hassle here? We can have an AR error term too if we feel strongly about it...

is the first approach wrong?

Likely yes, as it is non-standard (so there is no detailed investigation of it compared to the alternative), it ignores the true longitudinal nature of data (which can be modelled fine with non-known methodologies, it introduces non-obvious hyperparameters (the $\alpha$) that themselves have a non-obvious effect on the variance of the final estimates, and it loses information from individuals with single observations (so no pooling - i.e. it is inefficient). As an added kicker, defining degrees-of-freedom/effective sample size will likely be very complex (so goodbye variance calculations).

What is your objective? Are you trying to estimate change / growth of y? Or are you simply trying to compare different repeated measures under different conditions? That is, is the fact that measurements are clustered in people a nuisance or part of your question? I also agree that adding the hyperparameter means you're making things much more complex without any clear added benefit.

Hi Rick, I am more interested in the second idea: "compare different repeated measures under different conditions". I have never seen anyone use the first approach I thought of... I am just curious in knowing why its not popular.

(Sorry typo I just saw): "(...) modelled fine with non-known methodologies (...)" should read "(...) modelled fine with now-known methodologies (...)". :D

lol! the first one made more sense to me :)
